# Select Distinct DTO in 10 million records with JPA/JPQL

Tags: java, postgresql, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to retrieve all the distinct rows in MyClazz. There are 2 million total rows. After `distinct` they are filtered down to about 500K, but this depends on var1 (varchar) and var2 (int), which are IDs of the table.

Running this with Kotlin and PostgreSQL, we get an Out of Memory Exception.
Would there be any better approach?

> ```
> import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
> import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
> [...]
> @Query("SELECT DISTINCT new MyClazzDAO(var1, var2) FROM MyClazz ")
> fun findDistinctModelsPerPlatform(): List<MyClazzDAO>
> ```

Comment: Turn on debug output so that the generated SQL is printed, then include it in your question

Comment: Thanks, I added the details to the question. Feel free to delete those comments (on stack overflow deleting comments happens quite often, and is encouraged to reduce noise)

Comment: Have you looked into pagination? An open ended query that fetches or can fetch everything from a database is always bound to run into issues unless you. limit the amount of data that can be returned. You have to look at the number of rows and the size/amount of the data in this rows.

Comment: In addition to the above, consider *why* do you want to fetch so many records form the DB. What is the purpose of this operation? You may find that sometimes a different approach is much more appropriate. E.g. a more low-level solution with JDBC and cursors. I am not saying that this solution is the one you should follow, just prompting you to widen the space of possible solutions. Bringing this many records into memory will almost always lead to problems! Good luck!

Comment: 1) Why do you want to load so many records? 2) don't use distinct but group by to make the query run faster. With distinct the DB has to load all rows